Typescript is required to install Angular 17
Is it necessary to have typescript installed globally to install Angular 17? I'm very worried about this, because in some places I read that typescript already comes with node, but the command to check the typescript version on my machine doesn't work
I need to install Angular 17 and in the Angular documentation it says this "Make sure you are using a supported version of TypeScript before updating your application. Angular v17 supports TypeScript version 5.2 or later."

Typescript is not mandatory globally to install Angular.
All you need is the CLI installed globally.
npm i @angular/cli@latest -g

or
npm i @angular/cli@17.3.11 -g


If you are facing issue running ng new <<project name>>, and you are getting the error "ng is not recognized as an internal or external command", please refer the below answer.
ng is not recognized as an internal or external command - SO Question
